# Setting style attributes dynamically and consistently between Chrome & FF

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/HW64y/

```
<div id='box' class='frustratingBox'></div>
```

```
.frustratingBox{
    border:5px solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-radius:25px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

The key line is an attempt to change a single style property in the JS:

```
var FB = document.getElementById('box');
FB.style['border-color'] = "#009900";
```

Problem: my box ends up green like I would expect in Chrome, but remains black per the stylesheet rule in FF.  What causes this difference, what exactly are these browsers doing differently with their style objects?  Using Zepto gives a slick and easy fix, but I'd like to properly understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style property names are camel-cased in JavaScript, so:

```
FB.style.borderColor = "#009900";
```

---

The DOM 2 specification includes a [list of valid style properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html), all following the camel-cased naming scheme. There are no references to supporting the CSS property names without transformation. Newer specifications/drafts may have changed this, but I couldn't find a good reference.

---

The links [quoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18132806/825789) provide indicate that  `style['border-color']` is in fact a non-standard, developer-friendly alternate access method supported by WebKit and Trident, but not Gecko or Opera.

Comment: because Chrome is awesome

Comment: Chrome probably implemented some extras (non-standard, I suppose, but makes sense). @WesleyMurch

Comment: I think this is the essence of the question, although perhaps the OP will just take this information and run, problem solved.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I found a link for the DOM2 section on that (see edit), but I'm not familiar enough with the newer specs to tell if Chrome is just inventing it, or following a new standard.

Comment: You are of course correct, this works in both browsers - but so if I understand correctly, everything works as expected in terms of manipulating the style object, but its member variables are just named differently in CSS and JS, nothing deeper?

Comment: (as a point of interest, the FB.style['border-color'] syntax that works in Chrome was a pure guess on my part originally - so big ups from me to the Chrome team for reading my mind successfully :P )

Comment: @user1807834 Yes, probably the DOM specification introduced the camel-cased property names to allow access via dot notation. Chrome and IE decided to also support the standard CSS names via bracket notation (see links on quoo's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using style['border-color'] as you are doing, the correct way to change the style is to camel case instead of hyphenate the property name. So the correct syntax is

`FB.style.borderColor = "#009900";`

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/33MZK/

Apparently it's a bug, see discussion here: http://mac-os-forge.2317878.n4.nabble.com/CSS-properties-vs-their-JS-bindings-on-the-style-object-td165125.html, and here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0655.html

Comment: Yes, apparently I type too slow.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit disheartening  to have my original answer pointed out as a duplicate seconds after I posted it though, without even giving me the time to load the other answer.

Comment: Nice links. What I understand from them is that it's not a bug, just Chrome and IE being good to us, by implementing some more intuitive, although non-standard.

Comment: I suppose it's one of those bug or feature things? It's not to spec, as you noted, and I'm having a bit of trouble following the second discussion I posted to figure out what conclusion they came to.

Comment: As far as I understood, the end up discussing an IE bug where the standard property cssFloat is not supported. Not too relevant for the issue here, IMO the most useful part of the whole discussion is [this](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0686.html).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent links, they clarify and reinforce the answer very well.  Here's hoping the CSS-homogenous solution becomes standard!